# Android: Upgrading material:1.0.0 library causing problems with BottomAppBar

Tags: android, upgrade, android-theme, material-components-android, bottomappbar

I'm upgrading com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 TO com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0 (or higher), to be able to use the Badge feature.

When I change the material:1.0.0 version to material:1.1.0 I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.chmo.mo, PID: 20098
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chmo.mo/com.chmo.mo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.chmo.mo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:81)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar.<init>(BottomAppBar.java:224)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar.<init>(BottomAppBar.java:215)
            ... 28 more
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chmo.mo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' //TRYING TO UPGRADE THIS MODULE FROM 1.0.0
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.11.5'
}
```

activity_main.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <!--TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" /-->

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:hideOnScroll="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnStop"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_stop"
                app:maxImageSize="56dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_play3"
                app:maxImageSize="56dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddToPlaylist"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_playlist3"
                app:maxImageSize="56dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_settings"
                app:maxImageSize="56dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java content:

```
package com.chmo.mo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
//import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSpec;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
//import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable; // THIS IS ONLY AVAILABLE STARTING implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

import com.chmo.mo.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private boolean playWhenReady = true;
    private int currentWindow = 0;
    private long playbackPosition = 0;
    boolean isPlayPressed=false;
    boolean playerInitialized=false;
    public String selectedTitle = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // CRASHING HERE WHEN UPGRADED TO material 1.1.0
    }

}
```

Comment: The error specifically says `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents`. What is the theme your activity uses?

Comment: You are right @ianhanniballake, I stopped reading through the Exception chain at the first 2 "Caused by" section. Needless to say that I'm new at Android development. I wouldn't have thought that a styling issue can cause such a fuss. I'm looking forward to gaining more experience in Android development. Thanks!

Comment: It is always *the last* 'Caused by' that is the most important one - that is the one that kicked off the issue in the first place. Best of luck going forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

You have to use `Theme.MaterialComponents` or a `.Bridge` theme as [app theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme). For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge">
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: i have tried with <style name="Theme.Made" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge">, <style name="Theme.Made" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents"> and other Material Components children, in my manifest i have android:theme="@style/Theme.Made", i still get that error when i try to do BadgeDrawable.create. What am i missing?